# What's the difference between lightbox and carousel regarding image gallery?

Tags: jquery, lightbox, carousel

It seems they are two different types of an image gallery.

lightbox, carousel.

What are they?
(believe it or not, I find hard to search for their meaning..)
Are there other types of image galleries?

Comment: Just look at how they work. Lightbox = image pops up in a new window (or layer) Carousel = image gallery scrolls (or swipes, or jumps) horizontally (usually) or vertically.

Comment: carousel could have book-flip animation then?